# spring StreamingResponseBody not recognized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, streaming

I would like to return a StreamingResponseBody in order to stream the contents in a spring controller:

```
@RestController
class MyController(MyService service) {
  @PostMapping("/test")
  Object test() {
    return service.data()
  }
}

@Service
class MyService {
  Object data() {
   File file=new File("Path to the pdf file");
   FileInputStream instream=new FileInputStream(file);
   StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
     instream.transferTo(out)
   };
   return ResponseEntity
     .ok()
     .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
     .body(stream)
  }
}
```

But I have the exception:
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class deegixl.framework.file.MyService$2$3$$Lambda$1416/0x00000008019d5240] with preset Content-Type 'application/pdf'

Which means that the ResponseEntity class has been recognized by spring (even if an Object is returned) but the StreaminResponseBody not.

I know that it would be easier if returning explicitly  ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> but this is an exemple and sometimes MyService returns also Pojo objects for Json serialisation.

I know also that it would probably work by converting the File to byte[] but I want to stream the response for performance reason.

Any idea of how solving that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 different controller methods that both map to the same path, one returning a `StreamingResponseBody` for pdf files and the other an `Object` for POJOs. The methods will get selected based on the request's `Accept` HTTP header's value. The controller methods would look something like below:

```java
    @GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(myService.getFile());
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = "application/json")
    public Object getData() {
        return myService.getData();
    }
```

And the service methods like below:

```java
    public StreamingResponseBody getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Path to the pdf file");
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);

        return out -> {
            instream.transferTo(out);
        };
    }
    
    public Object getData() {
        Map<String, String> someObject = new HashMap<>();
        someObject.put("someKey", "someValue");
        
        return someObject;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but in fact the service can return Pojo or ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>. The controller doesn't know which class is returned by the service. So I cannot use your exemple